# Exception not caught in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, system-error

I have a try/except block for which I can't raise any exceptions. The block is simply as follows:

```
try:
    os.system("notepad+ "+out_file_path)
except SomeException:
    print("Make sure you have notepad+ in your %PATH% and try again")
```

Please note that I have intentionally used "notepad+" (which doesn't exist) to cause the exception.

I tried (`OSError`, `RuntimeError`, `OSError(winerror)` and `Exception`) as "SomeException" in the above-mentioned code, but any how I can't get the message printed and in all cases this is what I receive:

```
'notepad+' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I wonder if such a system error can override all exceptions (I.e. not get caught) or there's anything else I should do for my code to work the way I want.

Comment: You can't catch that exception. My advice is to switch to `subprocess`. It's much more robust. Having said that, if you really need to use `os.system`, you have to check the return code of `os.system` for a non-zero value.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for!